# UML class diagram for restaurant and Analysis to Design..

Tags: uml, analysis, class-diagram, ooad

I'm studying for a reexam in OOAD and doing some old exam questions. I'm trying to develop an analysis class model that may be used to manage a restaurant's menus. Here are the requirements:

Several different menus (breakfast,lunch,dinner)
Dishes may exists in several different menus
The restaurant also provides catering
Dishes should keep information which is relevant for guests with special requests (vegetarian,allergies etc..) Special menus may be created using this information as search criteria.

How I should model the catering? Should there be a Menu class and then breakfast,lunch,dinner and special as specialization classes or should I just have one Menu class? Should there be specialization classes for vegetarian,gluten free..etc dishes?

Then I have this question which confuses me a bit..
"What are 4 tasks that must be addressed when you transform this analysis class model into a design model?"

What is meant by this? Are there 4 general tasks/steps that always should be done when translating an analysis model into a design model or is it 4 specific tasks specifically for this analysis class model?

I've looked thorugh the presentations and the book (OOAD with applications) and the only thing I found related to these 4 steps/tasks was in a case study:

■ Identify the architectural elements at the given level of abstraction to further establish the problem boundaries and begin the object-oriented decomposition.
■ Identify the semantics of the elements, that is, establish their behavior and attributes.
■ Identify the relationships among the elements to solidify their boundaries and collaborators.
■ Specify the interface of the elements and then their refinement in preparation for analysis at the next level of abstraction.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I should model the catering? Should there be a Menu class and then breakfast,lunch,dinner and special as specialization classes or should I just have one Menu class? Should there be specialization classes for vegetarian,gluten free..etc dishes?

You should be modeling your business requirements. In your case, the requirements you have are from your exam task only. So you will have to decide what you include in your model. Only include in your business domain model what you think you will need to hold a state, or perform an operation on.

> Should there be specialization classes for vegetarian,gluten free..etc dishes?

Should be possible to save that in a simple boolean flag in the meal class, don't you think?

The "4 tasks" question is open for interpretation and is probably best answered when you have the documents from your studies available. At least I'd consider the 4 tasks you list a reasonable answer to the question.

Welcome to StackOverflow.

If you post your modeling attempts as a image file, you may receive more detailed help. You may use a service like dropbox to reference graphics until you have enough reputation for uploads to SO.

Comment: This is my analysis class diagram: http://i59.tinypic.com/2ccv4af.png

Still not sure about the "4 tasks" question.. if it means when transforming to a design model or a class design model..

Comment: Ok but the latter would be a valid question to ask the exam author. And better than doing guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

Class diagram by myself,for reference.

[image]